# Divide matrix to sub matrices (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, matrix, methods

I need this for a codewars challenge to make my code DRY
I have an array of arrays, lets say a 9x9 matrix.

```
const sudokuTest2= [
  [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
  [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3, 4, 9],
  [1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0],
  [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0],
  [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
  [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
  [9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4],
  [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
  [3, 0, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 9],
];
```

How can I divide it automatically into 9 equal areas, something which results from the following sample code:

```
const areas = [];

areas[0] = sudokuTest2[0]
  .slice(0, 3)
  .concat(sudokuTest2[1].slice(0, 3))
  .concat(sudokuTest2[2].slice(0, 3));
areas[1] = sudokuTest2[3]
  .slice(0, 3)
  .concat(sudokuTest2[4].slice(0, 3))
  .concat(sudokuTest2[5].slice(0, 3));
areas[2] = sudokuTest2[6]
  .slice(0, 3)
  .concat(sudokuTest2[7].slice(0, 3))
  .concat(sudokuTest2[8].slice(0, 3));

areas[3] = sudokuTest2[0]
  .slice(3, 6)
  .concat(sudokuTest2[1].slice(3, 6))
  .concat(sudokuTest2[2].slice(3, 6));
areas[4] = sudokuTest2[3]
  .slice(3, 6)
  .concat(sudokuTest2[4].slice(3, 6))
  .concat(sudokuTest2[5].slice(3, 6));
areas[5] = sudokuTest2[6]
  .slice(3, 6)
  .concat(sudokuTest2[7].slice(3, 6))
  .concat(sudokuTest2[8].slice(3, 6));

areas[6] = sudokuTest2[0]
  .slice(6, 9)
  .concat(sudokuTest2[1].slice(6, 9))
  .concat(sudokuTest2[2].slice(6, 9));
areas[7] = sudokuTest2[3]
  .slice(6, 9)
  .concat(sudokuTest2[4].slice(6, 9))
  .concat(sudokuTest2[5].slice(6, 9));
areas[8] = sudokuTest2[6]
  .slice(6, 9)
  .concat(sudokuTest2[7].slice(6, 9))
  .concat(sudokuTest2[8].slice(6, 9));
```

For sure I could use some nested loops, but I'm curious if there is any solution with array methods.
What will be the best solution, what do you think?

Comment: This question might be better suited to [codereview.se]. However be sure to take their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read their [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting.

Comment: _"What will be the best solution"_ - Define "best". _"what do you think?"_ - Asking for opinions is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take generate the wanted 3x3 parts by using a nested mapping.

```js
const
    sudoku = [[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3, 4, 9], [1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0], [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0], [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1], [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6], [9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4], [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5], [3, 0, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 9]],
    areas = Array
        .from({ length: 3 })
        .flatMap((_, i) => Array
            .from(
                { length: 3 },
                (__, j) => Array
                    .from({ length: 3 })
                    .flatMap((___, k) => sudoku[j * 3 + k].slice(i * 3, (i + 1) * 3)
            )
        ));

areas.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in with single `forEach` method. The idea behind this is dynamic indexing.

```js
const matrix = [ [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],  [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3, 4, 9],  [1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0],  [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0],  [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],  [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],  [9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4],  [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],  [3, 0, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 9],];


let areas = new Array(9).fill([]);

matrix.forEach((numbers, idx)=> {

  let segment = Math.floor(idx / 3);  
  areas[segment]      = [...areas[segment],     ...matrix[idx].slice(0, 3)];
  areas[segment + 3]  = [...areas[segment + 3], ...matrix[idx].slice(3, 6)];
  areas[segment + 6]  = [...areas[segment + 6], ...matrix[idx].slice(6, 9)];

})

areas.forEach(area => console.log(...area));
```